# javascript capture every value in a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div in which I render through javascript inputs and text dynamically. I am trying to capture the text of this div (both input values and text).

My first step if to capture the parent div:

```
let answerWrapper = document.getElementById("typing-answer-wrapper");
```

The issue now is that using the innerHTML will give me the whole html string with the given tags and using the inerText will give me the text, excluding the tags.

In the following case scenario:

[image]

the console inspect is:
[image]

What is the way to capture: $2.4 if the inputs have 2 and 4
and $null.null if the inputs are blank.

Any help is welcome

Comment: Write the HTML as HTML not as a console inspect

Comment: post your html also

Comment: That looks like angular syntax. Why do you want to do these things using DOM API? (Or is this a third party website and you're trying to get values from some elements?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over all of the element's child nodes and concatenate their `wholeText` or `value` else 'null'. For inputs the `wholeText` will be undefined. If they have no value we'll return 'null'. Be aware that spaces and line-breaks will also be included so you may want to strip these later (or skip them in the loop) but as a proof of concept see the following example:

```js
var typingAnswerWrapper = document.getElementById("typing-answer-wrapper");
function getVal(){ 
  var nodeList = typingAnswerWrapper.childNodes;
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    var item = nodeList[i];
    str+=(item.wholeText || item.value || "null");
  }
  console.log(str);
}
getVal();
//added a delegated change event for demo purposes:
typingAnswerWrapper.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  if(e.target.matches("input")){
    getVal();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="typing-answer-wrapper">$<input type="number" value=""/>.<input type="number" value="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could do it :

```js
function getValue() {
  var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('typing-answer-wrapper')[0],
    text = [];
  const children = [...parent.getElementsByTagName('input')];
  children.forEach((child) => {
    if (child.value == '')
      text.push("null")
    else
      text.push(child.value)
  });
  if (text[0] != "null" && text[1] == "null") text[1] = "00";
  document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "$" + text[0] + "." + text[1]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="typing-answer-wrapper">
  $
  <input type="number"> .
  <input type="number">
</div>

<button onclick="getValue()">get value</button>

<div id="value"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Islam Elshobokshy although "$" and "." are not standard characters. Like I said in the description, the content is rendered dynamically and can be any character. Thank you for the effort though.

Answer (score -1):

You can fetch input feild values by their respective ids `$('#input_feild_1').val()` will give the first feild value and similarly `$('#input_feild_2').val()` for second feild and contruct use them to construct whatever as u wish. As in your case this should work 
value_1 = `$('#input_feild_1_id').val()`
value_2 = `$('#input_feild_2_id').val()`

you need something like `"$ + value_1 + . + value_2"`

Comment: He's neither using ids nor using jquery.